# How can I make tasker close these apps as though I've swiped them away?

Tags: nexus-5, tasker

I want to make it close all the apps in here.

[image]

I've tried this already:

[image]

But it doesn't do as intended, since the apps dont leave the recents. Any ideas?

Comment: Just want to confirm: you want to *close & remove* all recent apps using Tasker? Killing an app (e.g. using Back button) doesn't mean it will be removed from recent list, which is by design.

Comment: I just want to remove the recents. They dont have to close. It annoys me to have them full and swiping them away is tedious.

Comment: Afraid there is no way to do so with *Tasker* ***yet*** (maybe the dev finds a way later). As Andrew already pointed to: the "Kill App" of *Tasker* just terminates the app, which doesn't mean it wasn't running lately – so it keeps staying in the recents' list.

Comment: I have a query: Do you want to clear all the apps in recent list, or just the apps listed in the image?

Comment: all of them in the list

Answer (score 1):

You don't need root, but you do need to have Tasker or equivalent.

Open Tasker, create a task, select "App" and select Launch App. Select the app that you want to hide from recent list. Put a check next to "Exclude From Recent Apps". Exit out of the action to save it.

You can then either open the app using Tasker or export the task as an app. Install the app that you've created. You can now load it without it showing on the recent list.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So I know this answers the question but I'm looking for a way to remove apps from recents using command line. Anything like that?

Comment: @Kristopher , there is a way to do so using Tasker if you  still need to do that

Answer (score -1):

You must manually close in your settings

Comment: Are you sure theres no task for it? Oh well. Thanks.